# How to get the type name of a template type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export class MyClass<T> {
  private myObject: ObjectType<T>;

  constructor(myObject: ObjectType<T>) {
    console.log(type name of T);  ?????
    this.myObject= myObject;
  }
}
```

I know that I can't do that at compile time, is there any trick to check the type name?

Comment: I don't think so, since that information is erased by the time the code is run (as Javascript).

Comment: Yep, not possible. Also, you're misusing generics if you try to do anything like that. A generic function / class / type shouldn't need to know anything about the generic type.

Comment: actually I need the type name in another place where I am using an object of type MyClass<T> where the behavior change according to T  type

Answer (score 1):

With classes, you can do as below. Does not work with interfaces or types, only instances of classes.

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {}

function isFoo(obj: Foo | Bar | null):boolean {
    return obj instanceof Foo;
}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log( isFoo(foo) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with vanilla Typescript. All types are erased during compilation. However, you can use a reflection library such as this one: https://github.com/Hookyns/ts-reflection